# Como utilizar el método Toxml en genexus?

Tags: xml, genexus

Tengo un User control que descargue de Marketplace, dicho control tiene un xml, el cual me genera el diagrama de gantt (motivo por el cual lo descargue) lo que deseo hacer es, Ingresar datos al diagrama de gantt, mediante una transacción, El user control dirige el xml, pero el xml se construye como string, lo que deseo hacer es antes de mandarlo construir el string. y convertir el string a xml.

*EN ESPECIFICO QUIERO SABER, COMO AGREGAR UN XML EN UN SDT...*

para llenar el siguiente diagrama:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

------------el xml es este:----------------------

```
<dataColumn align='center' headerfontcolor='ffffff'  headerbgColor='000000'  bgColor='eeeeee' headerText='Dur.' width='35' isBold='0'>
    <text label='150' /> 
    <text label='340' />
    <text label='60' />
    <text label='20' /> 
    <text label='30' />
    <text label='45' />
    <text label='40' />
    <text label='102' /> 
    <text label='60' />
    <text label='30' />
    <text label='90' />
    <text label='30' />
</dataColumn>
<dataColumn headerbgColor='000000' headerfontcolor='ffffff'  align='right' fontColor='000000' bgColor='5FB404' bgAlpha='25' headerText='Entorno' >
    <text label='$400' /> 
    <text label='$890' />
    <text label='$1234' />
    <text label='$230' /> 
    <text label='$450' />
    <text label='$120' />
    <text label='$1780' />
    <text label='$3330' /> 
    <text label='$890' />
    <text label='$1110' />
    <text label='$260' />
    <text label='$460' />
</dataColumn>
```

------y la trn con la que quiero trabajar es esta::----------

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Karen y bienvenida a SO en español. Te invito a visitar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio y que mires algunas preguntas ya realizadas para familiarizarte un poco. Es importante también que mires un poco la página sobre [¿Cómo preguntar?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lo mejor es que investigues un poco por tu cuenta y publiques la parte del código importante para ayudarte a resolver el problema :). Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Karen,

Lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Crear un Objeto SDT en GeneXus, que es el que te permitirá crear el XML que necesitas.
2. Crear un Procedimiento o DataProvider que a partir de la Transacción, llene el SDT anterior.
3. Obtener el Texto del SDT:
   &Text = &SDTGant.ToXml()

Luego ese &Text es lo que le pasas al diagrama.

Para aclararte mejor el tema, [te adjunto un XPZ](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14729664/Gantt.xpz) que puedes importar en GeneXus X Evolution 3, en donde ya te creé el SDT que necesitas.

[Documentación del Control Gantt](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?15410,GXjsGantt%20User%20Control)

Comment: Muchas Gracias, hasta hoy lo vi, pero hoy retome ese proyecto, ya que me pidieron otras cosas con mas prioridad, lo probare. Gracias :)